# TCL run Powershell script file

Tags: powershell, tcl

i'm doing TCL script but i need a value which is called Powershell script to get AD attribute value back to TCL. I have no idea how to use TCLscript to call Powershell script or powershell scriptfile but i found the below sample but i could not get it to work.

```
proc execPowershellCmd {cmd} {
     set cmd "-command $cmd"
     foreach chan {stdin stdout stderr} {
             lassign [chan pipe] rd$chan wr$chan
     }
     if {[catch {
        package require twapi_process
        set cmd [string map [list \" \\\"] $cmd]
        twapi::create_process [auto_execok powershell] -cmdline $cmd -showwindow hidden \
         -inherithandles 1 -stdchannels [list $rdstdin $wrstdout $wrstderr]
     } ret]} {
        return [list -1 "" $ret]
     }
     chan close $wrstdin; chan close $rdstdin; chan close $wrstdout; chan close $wrstderr
     foreach chan [list $rdstdout $rdstderr] {
             chan configure $chan -encoding cp850 -blocking true; # -buffering full?; # -enc?
     }
     set out [read $rdstdout]; set err [read $rdstderr]
     chan close $rdstdout; chan close $rdstderr
     return [list [string compare $err ""] $out $err]
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question and add more details. Explain what kind of Powershell command you are trying to run. And why mix TCL into it?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I believe you just need to pass the commands you'd use if you tried running the powershell script through a powershell instance. So something like `ps pathtoyourfile.ps1` and you'd call it like `execPowershellCmd "ps pathtoyourfile.ps1"` in your Tcl script

Comment: @Jerry, not working. i think sample i found may not run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of the above shown snippet, and let me say you: it runs.
The example, though, needs the TWAPI extension to work, which my not clearly stated at https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Windows+PowerShell.
The proc `execPowershellCmd` runs a single Powershell cmd, here is a more complete example:

```
# Variante, die auch von WISH geht. Synchroner Aufruf eines einzelnen Befehls(blocks).
# Powershell wird jedesmal beendet.

################################################################################
##### Calls a single Powershell command (blocking, hidden)
### Arg: The command to give to Powershell via -command switch
### Ret: A List of three elements:
###  -1 "" <errtext>       -> error from packa re or create_process (twapi)
###   0 <stdouttxt> ""     -> Ok
###   1 "..." <stderrtext> -> Maybe Ok, something written to stderr
#
proc execPowershellCmd {cmd} {
     set cmd "-command $cmd"
     foreach chan {stdin stdout stderr} {
             lassign [chan pipe] rd$chan wr$chan
     }
     if {[catch {
        set cmd [string map [list \" \\\"] $cmd]; # muss noch in Wiki...
        twapi::create_process [auto_execok powershell] -cmdline $cmd -showwindow hidden \
         -inherithandles 1 -stdchannels [list $rdstdin $wrstdout $wrstderr]
     } ret]} {
        return [list -1 "" $ret]
     }
     chan close $wrstdin; chan close $rdstdin; chan close $wrstdout; chan close $wrstderr
     foreach chan [list $rdstdout $rdstderr] {
             chan configure $chan -encoding cp850 -blocking true; # -buffering full?; # -enc?
     }
     set out [read $rdstdout]; set err [read $rdstderr]
     chan close $rdstdout; chan close $rdstderr
     return [list [string compare $err ""] $out $err]
}

package require twapi

lassign [execPowershellCmd {
write-host "Guten Abend von der PowerShell..."
start-sleep -s 10
write-host "...10s Wartezeit sind um!"
# Fehlermeldungen brechen hier nicht mehr hart auf dem Bildschirm durch...
# falsch
exit
}] rc out err
puts "rc: $rc"
puts "out: $out"
puts "err: $err"
```

The output is as follows:

```
c:\Users\matthiasu\usr\pgm\tcl\usr\Tst\powershell>tclkitsh ps9.tcl
rc: 0
out: Guten Abend von der PowerShell...
...10s Wartezeit sind um!

err:

c:\Users\matthiasu\usr\pgm\tcl\usr\Tst\powershell>
```